# Can not run Renderscript HelloCompute example on Android GB 2.3.5

Tags: android, renderscript

I try to run Renderscript example HelloCompute on Android 2.3.5.

( I use **v22.2.1-833290** and **SDK 22.2.1**
I got an error message from Logcat:

```
W/dalvikvm( 4928): VFY: unable to resolve static method 412: Landroid/renderscript  /RenderScript;.create (Landroid/content/Context;)Landroid/renderscript/RenderScript;  
W/dalvikvm( 4928): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4002d560)  
E/AndroidRuntime( 4928): FATAL EXCEPTION: main  
E/AndroidRuntime( 4928): java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:   android.renderscript.RenderScript.create
```

In order to make apk package, I added **Android Support library v13** into build step.

I guess that renderscript library was not added correctly into build step. 
Sorry I could not find **Android Support Library v8** as following post
http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2013/09/renderscript-in-android-support-library.html

How can overcome this issue ?

Comment: I have the same problem. Eclipse shows "android.support.v8.renderscript" cannot be resolved error.

Comment: Same problem here. Can't resolve it..

Comment: Same problem here.  Followed http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/renderscript/compute.html#access-rs-apis to the letter but to no avail.  I'm using ADT v22.2.1-833290 as well, which I'm running on Mac OSX.

Comment: I have added a request for help to the Android Developers Google Group here: https://groups.google.com/forum/?hl=en#!topic/android-developers/11HUoezkR2M .  We'll see how long it takes to find the answer.

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at /build-tools/18.1.0/lib/renderscript-v8.jar

Comment: Thanks your pointing out. 
For my case: It seems that I found jar file in different directory 
build-tools/android-4.3/renderscript/lib/renderscript-v8.jar.
But I faced another problem. Following is logcat:

//------------------ Below ------------------
W/dalvikvm(19423): Unable to resolve superclass of Landroid/support/v8/renderscript/RenderScript$2; (122)
W/dalvikvm(19423): Link of class 'Landroid/support/v8/renderscript/RenderScript$2;' failed

TO be continued

Comment: E/dalvikvm(19423): Could not find class 'android.support.v8.renderscript.RenderScript$2', referenced from method android.support.v8.renderscript.RenderScript.setErrorHandler
W/dalvikvm(19423): VFY: unable to resolve new-instance 645 (Landroid/support/v8/renderscript/RenderScript$2;) in Landroid/support/v8/renderscript/RenderScript;
...
//------------------ Above ------------------

Android is new for me. Therefore, I'm not able to debug it.

Comment: Which IDE do you use?

Comment: I use ADT v22.1 (Eclipse)
Error message in previous post is Logcat.

Comment: I meant: do you use IDEA, Eclipse or Android Studio?

Comment: He answered your question.  He's using Eclipse.  And so am I, and having the same problem.  Query, vonbk: Using ADT v22.1 on Mac OSX?

Answer (score 3):

I suffer a similar problem, but finally resolved.

my experience :

I refer to this link->  http://www.doubleencore.com/2013/10/renderscript-for-all/ to import android.support.v8.renderscript.

then encountering an error->

VFY: unable to resolve static method 106: Landroid/support/v8/renderscript/RenderScript; create (Landroid / content / Context ;) Landroid/support/v8/renderscript/RenderScript;.

Finally found my mistakes,I forget to enable the jar at "Order and Export" of  "Java Build Path" .

After enable the jar, my app can finally work.

hope my experience can help anyone. :)

Answer (score 2):

The v13 support library is for Honeycomb, you need the v8 support library. You also have to reference `android.support.v8.renderscript`, not `android.renderscript`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.
I modified as follows:
**import android.renderscript** -> **import android.support.***
Since there is no **android support library v8** under the directory
**android/sdk/extras/android/support** ( available libraries are v4,v7,v13)
Do you know where I can get **prebuilt jar** file of **android support library v8**

Comment: Have you installed the SDK build-tools v18.1 through the SDK manager? Follow the instructions here - http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/renderscript/compute.html#access-rs-apis

Comment: Yes, I followed the instruction as following address 
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/renderscript/compute.html#access-rs-apis

And I installed "Android Support Library" with SDK Manager by 
selecting "Extras/Android Support Library" checkbox. 
But there was no "Android Support Library v8" under 
"android/sdk/extras/android/support" directory after 
installation had finished ( available directory are only 
v4,v7,v13) as I said before.

Answer (score 1):

add this line into your .classpath:

`<classpathentry kind="lib" path="out/target/common/obj/JAVA_LIBRARIES/android-support-v8-renderscript_intermediates/javalib.jar"/>`

Alternatively, Build Path -> Configure Build Path -> Libraries -> Add JARs -> add "out/target/common/obj/JAVA_LIBRARIES/android-support-v8-renderscript_intermediates/javalib.jar"

Answer (score 1):

[From here](http://android-developers.blogspot.co.il/2013/09/renderscript-in-android-support-library.html):

> In your project.properties, make sure you’re targeting android-18 and
> add the following lines:
>
> renderscript.target=18
>
> renderscript.support.mode=true sdk.buildtools=18.1.0

Now clean the project. You should see renderscript-v8.jar added to your Android Dependenmcies.

Answer (score 1):

I was getting this error:

```
E/AndroidRuntime(12762): Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: no static or non-static method "Landroid/support/v8/renderscript/RenderScript;.nDeviceSetConfig(JII)V"
```

I needed to have this in my build.gradle

```
renderscriptTargetApi 22
renderscriptSupportModeEnabled true
```

And then needed to add this to my custom proguard rules for release builds

```
# Renderscript support library
-keep class android.support.v8.renderscript.** { *; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just Copy /build-tools/24.0.3/renderscript/lib/renderscript-v8.jar to your project libs folder and add this to your dependencies  `compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])`
This worked for me, hope it helps you too.